# Reasoning about decreasing functions

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Is it valid to say that for $n > \frac{9}{2}$,

> $\dfrac{n+6}{2n-9}$ is a strictly decreasing function?

Since $2n$ increases faster than $n$ in all cases, is any additional argument needed to establish this?

I ask because I am trying to show that for $n \ge 31$,

$$\frac{n+6}{2n-9} < \frac{7}{10}$$

If $\dfrac{n+6}{2n-9}$ is strictly decreasing, then I only need to point out that $\dfrac{37}{53} < \dfrac{7}{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(n)=\frac{n+6}{2n-9} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{21}{2(2n-9)} $$
$g(n)=2n-9$ is a positive an increasing function for $n>\frac{9}{2}$, hence $f(n)$ is a positive and decreasing function on the same interval.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That really helps me to understand how to analyze the function!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n+6}{2n-9} = \frac{n-9/2 + 9/2 + 6}{2n-9} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{21}{4n-18}.$$

Since $1/2$ is constant and $21/(4n-18)$ is strictly decreasing for $n > 9/2$ then so is your sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=\dfrac{x+6}{2x-9}$ for $x >9/2$, then $f'(x)=\dfrac{-3}{(2x-9)^2}<0$, hence $f$ is strictly decreasing.